# Setting a Dialplan for guests?

Tags: asterisk

I am trying to configure my asterisk to regsiter every user who tries to connect to it, and allow it to establish calls. I have read that I should set "allowguest = yes" in sip.conf. 
What about the dialplan in extensions.conf ? What should I add so that all my users could make and recieve calls ? (this is my first questions).

I would go even more precise about the users : is it possible to allow only guests from one precise domain ? If yes please help find how to do it, I will be very thankful.

Answer (score 0):

Guest calls will go to default context which is in general section of sip.conf

```
[general]
context=some_restricted_access
```

About dialplan for calls - you need read some book for beginner or install freepbx/other web which do dialplan for you.

No, you can't allow guests from domain. But you can try play with realm= setting or allow access from one ip by using ip-authentification.